# Ubuntu 16.04, WIFI internet get lost when connect LAN wire

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet, ethernet

I'm connected with WiFi and the internet is running well, soon I connect the LAN wire which is connected to a NAS I lose the internet.
WIFI get the IP over DHCP from Router, 192.168.2.xxx
My wire connection I set to 192.168.2.111
the NAS have 192.168.2.105
I can see all files on the NAS but the internet is no more working.
If I disconnect the wire the internet is back to normal.

What do I wrong

Comment: Give us output from command 'route -n' when you are connwcted only to wifi, and again when you are connected to both connection. Problem cause changes of default gateway when you connect cable.

Comment: Please add also output of `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `ifconfig`

Comment: Sorry about my poor explanation. I add EDIT 1 in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem occurs because both your interfaces are on the same subnet

```
 enp3s0    -> addr:192.168.2.111
 wlp2s0    -> addr:192.168.2.125
```

In network topology

```
--------      wifi        ----------  
|      |------------------| router |
|  PC  |                  ----------
|      |----------| lan   --------
--------          |-------|  NAS |
                          --------
```

The solution will be to change the subnet on one link, wifi or lan.

If you do not use `lan` link except to access `NAS`, on lan card, do not use gateway setting. It's enough to set up IP and network mask.

When I say to change subnet I meat to change networks, not only subnet mask.

Example of setup

```
enp3s0
      ip: 192.168.3.111
      nm: 255.255.255.0
      gw: 192.168.3.1

wlp2s0    
      ip: 192.168.2.125
      nm: 255.255.255.0
```

In this setup you must change ip address on router lan port to`192.168.3.1`

Comment: Hi i try this and change the subnet to 255.255.255.128.
but no different.